# i want to display data in the same card as two columns any suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
      .card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
    
    }
    .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    .container {
      padding: 2px 16px;
    }
    .card {
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
    
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div><input type="text" id = "1" name="dataKey" placeholder="Enter id you want to serch" required>
      <button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick= goodfunction()>Submit</button></div>
<p></p>
        <div class="card">
        <div class="container" id="101">
          <h4><b>PRODUCTID</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE PRODUCTID </P>
          <h4><b>TERRITORY</b></h4>
          <p1>IT WILL DISPLAY THE TERRITORY</p1>
          <h4><b>LANGUAGE</b></h4>
          <p2>IT WILL DISPLAY THE LANGUAGE OF MOVIE</p2>
          <h4><b>STARTDATE</b></h4>
          <p3>IT WILL DISPLAY THE STARTDATE</p3>
          <h4><b>ENDDATE</b></h4>
          <p4>IT WILL DISPLAY THE END DATE</p4>
          <h4><b>EXCLUSIVITY</b></h4>
          <p5>IT WILL SHOW THE EXCLUSIVITY</p5>
          <h4><b>ACQUIRING DIVISION</b></h4>
          <p6>IT WILL DISPLAY THE ACQUIRING DIVISION</p6>
          <h4><b>PRODUCT TITLE</b></h4>
          <p7>IT WILL DISPLAY THE PRODUCT TITLE</p7>
          <h4><b>MEDIA</b></h4>
          <p8>IT WILL DISPLAY THE MEDIA RIGHTS</p8>
          <h4><b>FORMAT</b></h4>
          <p9>IT WILL DISPLAY THE FORMAT</p9>
          <h4><b>OWNER</b></h4>
          <p10>IT WILL DISPLAY THE OENER OF THE MPVIE</p10>
    
        </div>
```

I have created a card I want to display data in the same card in two columns

I have used div width 50% but I am unable to divide it so the end user will not scroll down

please help me I have used all the dividing things but I am unable to divide it

thanks in advance

Comment: You should not have html elements like buttons and other in the head section!

Comment: you can use two tables in same div

Comment: should each card have a box-shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    .container {
      padding: 2px 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div><input type="text" id="1" name="dataKey" placeholder="Enter id you want to serch" required>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=g oodfunction()>Submit</button></div>



  <p></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="container" id="101">
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <h4><b>PRODUCTID</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE PRODUCTID </P>
          <h4><b>TERRITORY</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE TERRITORY</p>
          <h4><b>LANGUAGE</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE LANGUAGE OF MOVIE</p>
          <h4><b>STARTDATE</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE STARTDATE</p>
          <h4><b>ENDDATE</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE END DATE</p>
          <h4><b>EXCLUSIVITY</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL SHOW THE EXCLUSIVITY</p>
        </div>
        <div>

          <h4><b>ACQUIRING DIVISION</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE ACQUIRING DIVISION</p>
          <h4><b>PRODUCT TITLE</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE PRODUCT TITLE</p>
          <h4><b>MEDIA</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE MEDIA RIGHTS</p>
          <h4><b>FORMAT</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE FORMAT</p>
          <h4><b>OWNER</b></h4>
          <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE OENER OF THE MPVIE</p>
        </div>
      </div>




    </div>
```

Comment: Although you example might solve the OP problem, it's still bad practice to have Html inside the Head

Comment: Also i notice the p1, p2, p3.. tags now. !! Corrected them as well :)

Comment: can we place the card at the center of the page

Comment: Check now please

Comment: THANKS A LOT 
I WANT the text to be allign in center   align = "center" i used align center proprtey but it is not working

Comment: You want the content also to be centered ?

Comment: Use     text-align: center; on the row div

Comment: i used but  i am unable if you can plese edit your code

Answer (score 0):

use this.. here i am using the flex property to style the code.. you can use this to divide the div into two columns

https://jsfiddle.net/68q9xbnc/5/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div><input type="text" id = "1" name="dataKey" placeholder="Enter id you want to serch" required>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick= goodfunction()>Submit</button></div>



    <p></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <style>
  .card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;

}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;

}
.container {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    column-count: 2;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 510px;
}
h4 {
  margin-right:15px;
}
p,p1,p2,p3,p5,p6 {
  max-width:50%;
}


  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="container" id="101">
      <h4><b>PRODUCTID</b></h4>
      <p>IT WILL DISPLAY THE PRODUCTID </P>
      <h4><b>TERRITORY</b></h4>
      <p1>IT WILL DISPLAY THE TERRITORY</p1>
      <h4><b>LANGUAGE</b></h4>
      <p2>IT WILL DISPLAY THE LANGUAGE OF MOVIE</p2>
      <h4><b>STARTDATE</b></h4>
      <p3>IT WILL DISPLAY THE STARTDATE</p3>
      <h4><b>ENDDATE</b></h4>
      <p4>IT WILL DISPLAY THE END DATE</p4>
      <h4><b>EXCLUSIVITY</b></h4>
      <p5>IT WILL SHOW THE EXCLUSIVITY</p5>
      <h4><b>ACQUIRING DIVISION</b></h4>
      <p6>IT WILL DISPLAY THE ACQUIRING DIVISION</p6>
      <h4><b>PRODUCT TITLE</b></h4>
      <p7>IT WILL DISPLAY THE PRODUCT TITLE</p7>
      <h4><b>MEDIA</b></h4>
      <p8>IT WILL DISPLAY THE MEDIA RIGHTS</p8>
      <h4><b>FORMAT</b></h4>
      <p9>IT WILL DISPLAY THE FORMAT</p9>
      <h4><b>OWNER</b></h4>
      <p10>IT WILL DISPLAY THE OENER OF THE MPVIE</p10>

    </div>
```

Comment: Although you example might solve the OP problem, it's still bad practice to have Html inside the Head

Comment: yes. thats a good point. actually i didnt notice that button inside the head. i just copy the code from the question and update the css only. i didnt even touch the html.. anyway good catch.. nice

Comment: Also there is nothing called P1,P2 and so on